# Win32 to Win64 porting compilation issue

Tags: c, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit, porting, win64

I am porting a project from Win32 to Win64. We are using make file but we get the following error

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(17) : error C2371: 'size_t' : redefinition; different basic types1>
        binding.cpp : see declaration of 'size_t'

        C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\winnt.h(81) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "No Target Architecture"
```

We are copmiling with following CFLAGS:

> 1> cl.exe   /nologo  /MTd /GR /W3 /Zi /EHsc /Od  /I "....\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\PlatformSDK\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include" /D_X86_  /D_WIN64 /D_WIN32 /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Fo".\Debug\" /Fd".\Debug\" /FD /c "test.cpp"

I don't know which settings I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

The header winnt.h expects that either `_AMD64_` or `_IA64_` should be defined when you're trying to compile the code in 64-bit mode.

They may be set by the compiler automatically if you use the right compiler. Check that you're using the 64-bit version of cl.exe.

Comment: 1> cl.exe   /nologo  /MTd /GR /W3 /Zi /EHsc /Od  /I "..\..\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include" /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\PlatformSDK\include" /I"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include" /D "_IA64_" /D "_WIN64" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Fo".\Debug\\" /Fd".\Debug\\" /FD /c "test.cpp"